# IntelliJ cannot compile as "Java resource does not exist"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ community edition 2016.1 with a single file 'test.java' in the src folder.

Whenever I compile or Make Project I get the below error. What is going wrong?
Unfortunately there is no information available on Google of what could be going wrong.

```
Information:Using javac 9-ea to compile java sources
Information:java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (9-ea). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder.findSingleModule(jdk.compiler@9-ea/ModuleFinder.java:223)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.setCompilationUnitModules(jdk.compiler@9-ea/Modules.java:347)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(jdk.compiler@9-ea/Modules.java:205)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initModules(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavaCompiler.java:1020)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initModules(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavaCompiler.java:1012)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavaCompiler.java:906)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavacTaskImpl.java:135)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(jdk.compiler@9-ea/JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:168)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:388)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:289)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:197)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:168)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1238)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:912)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:984)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:871)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:696)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:387)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:194)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:294)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@9-ea/Executors.java:514)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@9-ea/FutureTask.java:266)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9-ea/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9-ea/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
Information:java:   at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-ea/Thread.java:804)
Information:java: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Java resource does not exist : SOURCE_PATH/SOURCE/module-info
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacFileManager.getJavaFileForInput(JavacFileManager.java:180)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedJavaFileManager.getJavaFileForInput(jdk.compiler@9-ea/ClientCodeWrapper.java:287)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder.getModuleInfoFromLocation(jdk.compiler@9-ea/ModuleFinder.java:231)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder.findSingleModule(jdk.compiler@9-ea/ModuleFinder.java:187)
Information:java:   ... 32 more
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'untitled'
Information:10/4/16 10:45 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5s 756ms
Error:java: java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Java resource does not exist : SOURCE_PATH/SOURCE/module-info
```

Comment: Are you using JDK-9 for compilation?

Comment: Selection 0 from update-alternatives --config javac:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javac

Comment: Java 9 is not out yet. You are using an early access version of Java 9. If you want a stable, production-ready version of Java, use Java 8, not the early access version of Java 9. There are most likely still bugs in the Java 9 compiler, or IntelliJ might not yet fully support it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create module-info.java file in the src directory with Your module definition.

See: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations

Example:

```
module com.foo.bar { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simply changing to Java 8 as Jesper suggested in the comments. It looks like IntelliJ doesn't currently support Java 9.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA should support Java 9 (I've tested it with a Java 9 JDK), but not all versions of JDK 9 are stable, hence the exception suggests the error is in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1** with **JDK 9 build 116**

You need to create **module-info.java** at **src**. Please see below:

> \src\module-info.java

```
module com.bsingh.java9 { }
```

> \src\com\bsingh\java9\Java9Main.java

```
package com.bsingh.java9;

public class Java9Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java 9 !!!");
    }
}
```

Then run Java9Main. You will see output as:

Hello Java 9 !!!